# zeroclipboard-copy to clipboard not working

Tags: jquery, zeroclipboard

I am using zeroclipboard to copy some url.

```
ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath(hostPath+'/scripts/ZeroClipboard.swf');
    $(function() {
        var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
        clip.setHandCursor( true );
        clip.addEventListener('mousedown',function() {
        var url=$('#customPURL').html();
        alert(url);
            clip.setText(url);
            showCopyMessage();
        });
        clip.glue('copy');
    });
```

I get correct alert for url which needs to get copied.but copy to clipboard is not working. No error in console. and i absolutely have no clue to fix this.

Any Help guys. Thanks For stopping by...!!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be occurring due to the *Clipboard Event*.  This particular problem often occurs, what you can do to remedy the issue is:

```
clip.addEventListener('onMouseOver', clipboardEvent);

function clipboardEvent() {
     clip.setText(finalText);
}
```

The goal is to add a *Listener* so that the *Clipboard* will become aware of any changes that may occur.